# Option Strict and Nulls

Tags: vb.net

I do not want empty strings in the database. When a field is null, I want it to be null.
I am trying to replace

```
If strStreet = "" Then
            cmd.Parameters("@Street").Value = DBNull.Value
        Else
            cmd.Parameters("@Street").Value = strStreet
        End If
```

with the VB If Operator as follows

```
 cmd.Parameters("@Street").Value = If(strStreet = "", DBNull.Value, strStreet)
```

I get the following message from the red squiggly under everything to the right of the first = sign.
"Cannot infer a common type, and Option Strict On does not allow 'Object' to be assumed."
OK, so I do a little cast

```
cmd.Parameters("@Street").Value = If(strStreet = "", CObj(DBNull.Value), strStreet)
```

The red squiggly disappears and a green squiggly appears under CObj saying redundant Cast.
Should I 
A. Turn off Option Strict
B. Ignore the green squiggly
C. Go back to my If...Else...End If
or something else??
BTW it works great in the other direction when I am preparing a string for the Text property of some control.

```
strStreet = If(reader.GetValue(2) IsNot DBNull.Value, reader.GetString(2), "")
```

I have read several question and answers here that are circling my problem but I can't quite get it.
Thank you for your kind attention.

Comment: A) is the least desirable answer, because `Option Strict` will catch some things that are errors that will not be picked up any other way.  I'd say either B) or C) at your preference, or you could also consider option D) which is to write a function returning `Object` that does the equivalent of the `If` block or the `If` statement.

Comment: This is due to how the single line `IF` statement works. [ref](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2008/03/12/orcas-introduces-the-if-operator-a-new-and-improved-iif-sophia-salim/)   *Note that the return type of the operator is decided based on the wider of the types of the truepart and the falsepart, e.g, if the truepart is an integer and the falsepart is a decimal, then decimal which is the wider of the two types will be the return value’s type* In the second usage that works, the two parts (truepart and falsepart) are `String`, it's why the compiler does't complain.

Comment: Errors cannot be ignored. Warnings should not be ignored but if you evaluate the potential risk you're being warned about and determine that no run-time error will result then it's safe to simply accept the warning.

Comment: I found that DBNull.Value is "Type DBNull.Value is not defined" This might be the root of the problem. I decided to go with the function. Thank you Craig, Chris and jmc for the infor and  the link from Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly is triggering the *redundant cast* warning, but with the following extension method you shouldn't get a warning and also have less code if there are many parameters.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module Extensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function GetDBNullIfEmpty(s As String) As Object
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) Then
            Return DBNull.Value
        Else
            Return s
        End If
    End Function

End Module
```

then you can set your parameter-value like this:

```
cmd.Parameters("@Street").Value = strStreet.GetDBNullIfEmpty
```

Comment: I marked your post as answer but I am still puzzled about the redundant cast. I did not understand the <Extension> tag so I did not include it in my implementation. Thank you.

Comment: I did add a Function close to this in my DataAccess class. I was unsure of the <Extension> tag, so I didn't use it. I will research and learn about it. Thank you, Mat.

Comment: The <Extension> tag defines the method as an [extension-method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods). If you create a new Module and copy the code from my answer, it will work exactly like i wrote.

Comment: I did some research about the _redundant cast_ warning. But you don't find much information about it. It seems you have some plugin installed in VS which is triggering this warning. (Maybe FxCop?)

Answer (score 0):

`Null` on `vb.net` is `Nothing` .. so, you can use these codes:

**This works fine on MYSQL Database:**

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Street", MySqlDbType.String).Value = If(strStreet = "" OrElse strStreet = Nothing, Nothing, strStreet)
```

**You could also use:**

```
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@Street", MySqlDbType.String).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(strStreet), CObj(System.DBNull.Value), strStreet)
```

**NOTE:**
In your `database` you must check if the field can contain `Null`. If not, it may fail.

> Will run with `Option Script On`

Comment: Nope. Firstly, you'd use `OrElse` rather than `Or` there. Secondly, you'd use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` or `String.IsNullOrWhitespace` rather than direct comparisons. Lastly and most importantly though, you'd never assign `Nothing` to an ADO.NET parameter's `Value` because that doesn't represent null in ADO.NET.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry. didn't know that. because it's running fine on me. i'm using MySQL Database in XAMPP. okay. i'll delete my post later on.

Comment: I don't use MySQL so it's possible that Connector/Net is smart enough to treat `Nothing` as null but I've never heard that that is the case. It's not an ADO.NET standard anyway, and there's no specific indication that this question relates to MySQL.

Comment: The OP didn't mention what DB he/she is using so I tried to help with what I know. should I delete this post or edit it?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have edited my Post. can you now remove my `DownVote`?

Comment: Done, but I'd still remove the ` = True` and also use `CObj` rather than `CType`.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I am using Microsoft SQL Server. I should have mentioned that. Thank you KiLLua and jmc.