# if() operator/function bugs dealing with nothing. IF() doesn't return nothing. Why?

Tags: vb.net

Most probable this is a bug reporting rather than asking question, however, if it's not so , and anyone knows why , please solve this paradox.

Function `IF(arg1, arg2, arg3)` isn't functioning in all circumstances as wisely described in MSDN. When `arg2` is `Nothing`, it doesn't return `Nothing` in special cases, particularly, when `arg1` is `TRUE` (`arg2` is `Nothing`) and `arg3` is not of nullable type. Instead it converts `Nothing` to arg3 type (sets defaults value of `arg3` type for `arg2`) and passes that value to `arg3`. The beneath code illustrates that issue\question\bug

Comments imply the behavior, message titles help to follow (if sequence is lost)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '

Dim V As Integer?
Dim D As Boolean = True
MsgBox(Nothing, vbOK, "'1st msgbox") '1st msgbox
MsgBox(If(D, Nothing, True), vbOK, "'2nd msgbox.") '2nd msgbox. If(D, Nothing, True) returns false instead of nothing
MsgBox(If(True, Nothing, True), vbOK, "3rd the same as 2nd") '3rd the same as 2nd, shows no matter either we use boolean variable or type the value directly
V = If(D, Nothing, 15)
MsgBox(V, vbOK, "4th msgbox, shows the problem isn't related to messaging the IF()...") '4th msgbox, shows the problem isn't related to messaging the IF() directly, or first, assigning it to a variable, capable of holding null
MsgBox(If(True, Nothing, 15), vbOK, "5th.") ' 5th. this returns different result (int format) but again not the expected nothing

'Now how it works
MsgBox(If(True, Nothing, "some text"), vbOK, "6th") ' 6th 'NOW this returns [Nothing] as expected, (probably) because string is nullable
MsgBox(If(True, Nothing, "some text") Is Nothing, vbOK, "7th proof of...") '7th proof of above result. Really nothing not string.empty

Dim UnevaluatedPart As Nullable(Of Integer)
MsgBox(If(True, Nothing, UnevaluatedPart), vbOK, "8th. Now it returns nothing") ' 8th. Now it returns nothing with integer? as third argument (false part)
MsgBox(If(True, Nothing, UnevaluatedPart) Is Nothing, vbOK, "' 9th. Proof of above") ' 9th. Proof of above (it's really nothing not empty string ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider putting the comment above the code rather than after, so we can read without having to scroll to the right for every line.

Comment: I concur with the recommendation to turn `Option Strict On`. Any code that requires `Option Strict Off` to compile is bad code.  Having `Option Strict On` makes you think about what types you're dealing with and that helps you write better code.  You also need to get a better understanding of what `Nothing` means in the context of each type. For all classes it means no object. For nullable value types, it means an object with no value, i.e. `HasValue` will be `False`. For non-nullable value types, it means the default value of that type, e.g. `False`, `#1/01/0001#`, `0`, etc.

Comment: I had a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46413980/option-strict-and-nulls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `If` operator can be thought of as being like a generic function:

```
If(Of T)(condition As Boolean,
         truePart As T,
         falsePart As T) As T
```

That means that the second and third arguments must be the same type (either explicitly or one can be cast as the other) and the return value will be that same type.  With that in mind, let's look at some of your examples.

```
'2nd msgbox. If(D, Nothing, True) returns false instead of nothing
MsgBox(If(D, Nothing, True), vbOK, "'2nd msgbox.")
```

So, for that to work at all, the second and third as the same type.  What type could that possibly be?  The type of the second argument is unspecified while the type of the third is `Boolean`. `Nothing` can be cast as type `Boolean` so that's what happens, and the return value is thus also `Boolean`.  Casting `Nothing` as type `Boolean` yields `False`, so the second argument is effectively `False` and that's what gets returned.

```
Dim UnevaluatedPart As Nullable(Of Integer)

' 8th. Now it returns nothing with integer? as third argument (false part)
MsgBox(If(True, Nothing, UnevaluatedPart), vbOK, "8th. Now it returns nothing")


' 9th. Proof of above (it's really nothing not empty string ""
MsgBox(If(True, Nothing, UnevaluatedPart) Is Nothing, vbOK, "' 9th. Proof of above")
```

In both these cases, the type of the second parameter is unspecified and the type of the third parameter is `Integer?` so `Nothing` gets cast as type `Integer?`.  That means that both the second and third arguments are a `Integer?` with no value.  You're going to get the same return value whether the condition is `True` or `False`.  Of course it won't be an empty `String` because the return value **MUST** be type `Integer?`.  It's not just `Nothing` though; it's a `Integer?` with no value, so you can actually test the `HasValue` property of that result.

```
' 5th. this returns different result (int format) but again not the expected nothing
MsgBox(If(True, Nothing, 15), vbOK, "5th.")
```

Again, the type of the second argument is unspecified so the argument and return type is inferred from the third argument.  That third argument is type `Integer` so that means that `Nothing` is cast as type `Integer`, which yields zero.  The condition is `True` so it is that zero value that gets returned.  If you tested whether that was equal to `Nothing` then you'd find that it is, which is exactly why that's what `Nothing` got converted to for the second parameter.

Comment: That's clear explanation! (IF it is so indeed) Thank you! They should have mention it in MSDN i think :)

Comment: Hey, jmcilhinney! Congratulations to 20k!

Comment: Why thank you VV. Now where's my chocolate reward? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In VB.NET [`Nothing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/nothing) has two meanings:

1. `null`(as in C#)
2. the default value of a given type (`default` in C#)

If you use the conditional operator with two types both must be convertible to each other. With `Nothing` and `True` it's possible because the default value of a `Boolean` is `False`.

So it's the same as the longer version

```
Dim bool1 As Boolean = Nothing ' False
Dim bool2 As Boolean = If(True, bool1, True)
```

`bool2` will be `False` because `bool1` is `False` because that's the default value of `Boolean`.

What you learn from this? Be careful with the `If` operator and implicit conversions and always remember that `Nothing` doesn't only mean `null` in VB.NET.

Also remember that value types like `Boolean` always have a value, they are never `null`. In this case `Nothing` really means "give me the default value".

Now an exercise :) What will be the result of the integer `i` here?

```
Dim i AS int32 = If(true, nothing, 777)
```

Comment: If it is so as you say, the question is "**Is there a way to mention single meaning Nothing in VB (null in C#)?**". The example you'v brought could be described simply, with standard logic, 'bool2' will be false, because 'bool1= false' (it will get 'bool1' value because the 'arg1=true', may be not because it is boolean's default).

Comment: cause i have `Nothing` there, does it check `arg3` to understand what kind of `Nothing` it is? In MSDN they say that `arg3` is not evaluated if `arg1` is true.

Comment: @Kaihusrav: 1.) you should really switch `Option Strict` to `On`, always and everywhere. You will learn a lot about the .NET type system and how to write safe and readable code. 2.) Sure, `bool2` will be false because `bool1` is false. But `bool1` is false because `Nothing` means here `default(Boolean)`. Otherwise that would not compile because  `Boolean` is a value type and not a nullable reference type. In C# you could not assign `null` to a `bool` variable, in VB you can because it is also the default operator.

Comment: And how is the 'given type' determined? would you check out the case of 4th msgbox. The variable `V` is of nullable type. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Kaihusrav: the 4th msg-box is pointless because this is actually a good example for why you should set `Option Strict` to `On`. This should never compile and it doesn't: _"Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Boolean' to 'Integer?'"_ This is invalid: `Dim V As Int32? = If(True, Nothing, True)`. The target type is a nullable integer, the first "type" in the conditional operator is `Nothing`. In this case it's treated as `Nullable(Int32)` because there is an implicit conversion from `Nothing` to any nullable type.

Comment: I have coded this project significantly, so i wonder would turning option strict in now will force me to change many or not. And may be that wouldn't be of much help in this specific case ... but may be it is, thank you for sugestion. Anyway, the question remains not curtain

Comment: @Kaihusrav: yes, it will force you to change many things. But it's worth it. The process of fixing it lets you review this code, understand what's happening and if that was even correct in the first place. The good thing is that you see all compiler errors immediately.

Comment: thanks, i made a mistake there, that wasn't my intention, replace here `V = If(D, Nothing, True)` the `True` with some int like `15` and you will get 0 instead of Nothing.

Comment: I am going to edit the question (last comment of mine) so some comments will look strange to visitors after ...

Comment: Thank you @Tim, i got the point. For pair (Nothing; 777) possible outcome types are 1) `integer` with `Nothing` representing default `0`, and 2) `integer?` with `Nothing` representing `Null`. And IF() function prefers the first interpretation. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

"If" needs a return value, when it looks at the parameter and see Nothing with a Boolean it says "Oh, I should return a Boolean". If you want to return a nullable Boolean, then one of the parameter need to be a Boolean?. Same with integer.

```
    Dim a As Boolean? = If(True, Nothing, True)
    Dim b As Boolean? = If(False, Nothing, True)
    Dim c As Boolean? = If(True, Nothing, CType(True, Boolean?))
    Dim d As Boolean? = If(False, Nothing, CType(True, Boolean?))

    Console.WriteLine(a) ' false
    Console.WriteLine(b) ' true
    Console.WriteLine(c) ' empty
    Console.WriteLine(d) ' true
```